# I'm having a minor issue with my address book program in C

Tags: c

I'm having a minor issue with my Address book, if I attempt to load the contact data without having entered and saving at least a single contact info, the program returns a "0" and freezes. Also, I feel that i need to add a remove contact function in this program as well, if anyone would help me out with that it'd be very much appreciated =D.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME    40
#define LNAME   40
#define ADDRESS 100
#define PCODE   6
#define PNUM    10
#define MAX     10

void Insert();
void Display();
void Search();
void Save();
void Load();
void Exit();

char temp [10];

typedef struct contact //defines the structure for our address book 

{
    char name   [NAME ];
    char Lname  [LNAME ];
    char address[ADDRESS];
    char Pcode  [PCODE];
    char Pnum   [PNUM];

}
contact;

int counter = 0;
int placeHolder = 0;
int loadContact;

int fileCount;

int save = 0;

FILE *PFileOut;

contact arrayContact [MAX];


int main()
{
    int option;
    char filechar;

    do
    {
    printf("\n***Personal Contact Book V1.0***\n\n");
    printf("1.Add new contact\n");
    printf("2.Display current contacts\n");
    printf("3.Search for a contact\n");
    printf("4.Save contacts to file\n");
    printf("5.Load contacts to file\n");
    printf("6.Exit\n\n");
    printf("> ");

    scanf("%d", &option);

    switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                Insert();
                break;

            case 2:
                Display();
                break;

            case 3:
                Search();
                break;

            case 4:
                Save();
                break;

            case 5:
                Load();
                break;

            case 6:
                Exit();
                break;

            default:
                printf("That is not a valid input, please choose between (1-6)");

        }
    }
    while(option !=6 );
}

void Insert()
{
         char option;
         if(placeHolder>=10){
                printf("Your contact list is full!");
                return;
        }
         do{
                printf("Contact Number: %d\n", counter+1);
                printf("First name: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", arrayContact[counter].name);
                printf("Last name: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", arrayContact[counter].Lname);
                printf("Address: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", arrayContact[counter].address);
                printf("Postal Code: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", arrayContact[counter].Pcode);
                printf("Phone: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", arrayContact[counter].Pnum);

                placeHolder++;
                counter++;

                printf("Press y/Y if you wish to add another contact, any key to return to main menu\n");
                scanf(" %c",&option);
                printf("\n");

         }while( (option =='y'|| option == 'Y')&& placeHolder<MAX);






}

void Display()
{
    counter = 0;
    while(counter<placeHolder){
        printf("Contact Number: %d\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nAddress: %s\nPostal Code: %s\nPhone: %s\n\n",counter+1,arrayContact[counter].name,
        arrayContact[counter].Lname,arrayContact[counter].address,arrayContact[counter].Pcode,arrayContact[counter].Pnum);
        counter++;
    }
    counter = placeHolder;
}

void Search()
{
    char search [40];
    char compare [40];
    int counterLetter;
    int counterContact;
    int verify = 0;

    printf("What is the contact's Last name? ");
    scanf(" %s", search);

    for( counterLetter = 0; search[ counterLetter ] != '\0'; counterLetter++ ) {
        search[ counterLetter ] = tolower( search[ counterLetter ] );
    }

    for( counterContact = 0; counterContact<placeHolder ; counterContact++ ){
        strcpy(compare,arrayContact[counterContact].Lname);

        for( counterLetter = 0; compare[ counterLetter ] != '\0'; counterLetter++ ) {
            compare[ counterLetter ] = tolower( compare[ counterLetter ] );
        }

        if( strcmp( search, compare ) == 0 ){
            printf("Contact Number: %d\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nAddress: %s\nPostal Code: %s\nPhone: %s\n\n",counterContact+1,
            arrayContact[counterContact].name,arrayContact[counterContact].Lname,arrayContact[counterContact].address,arrayContact[counterContact].Pcode,
            arrayContact[counterContact].Pnum);
            verify = 1;
        }
    }

    if(verify == 0){
        printf("No results found");
    }

}

void Save()
{
    PFileOut = fopen("Contact Book.dat","w");
    fprintf(PFileOut,"%d\n",placeHolder);
    for(counter = 0;counter<placeHolder;counter++){
        fprintf(PFileOut,"\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s",arrayContact[counter].name,arrayContact[counter].Lname,arrayContact[counter].address,arrayContact[counter].Pcode,
        arrayContact[counter].Pnum);
    }
    fclose(PFileOut);
    save = 1;

    printf("\nSuccessfully Saved!!\n");
}

void Load()
{
    char temp[40];
    PFileOut = fopen("Contact Book.dat","r");
    fscanf(PFileOut, "%d", &fileCount);
    printf("%d\n", fileCount);
    while(!feof(PFileOut)){
        fscanf(PFileOut,"%s",&arrayContact[placeHolder].name);
        fscanf(PFileOut,"%s",&arrayContact[placeHolder].Lname);
        fscanf(PFileOut," %[^\n]s",&arrayContact[placeHolder].address);
        fscanf(PFileOut,"%s",&arrayContact[placeHolder].Pcode);
        fscanf(PFileOut, " %[^\n]s",&arrayContact[placeHolder].Pnum);
        placeHolder++;
    }
    fclose(PFileOut);
}

void Exit()
{   char option6;
    while(save!=1){
        printf("It seems you have not saved your progress. Would you like to save? (y/n)");
        scanf(" %c", &option6);
        if(option6 == 'y'|| option6 == 'Y')
            {
                Save();
            }
        else
        {
            puts ("\nThank you for using Contact Book");

            exit(0);
        }
    }
    puts ("\nThank you for using Contact Book");
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: That is far too much code. Narrow it down using a debugger

Comment: You should read a basic C book/tutorial first.

Comment: @ed, i'm sorry i'm new and this is my first question, how does using a debugger narrow the code down?

also, I wrote most of the code up there, I just can't figure out why that issue pops up

Comment: @Terrified_Prinny - Use the debugger to find out where the problem occurs (stepping though the code checking what is happening against what should be happening). When you find these diverge you have spotted the problem area. You can then either fix it of if still have a problem write a small program to reproduce it.

Comment: `" %[^\n]s"` remove `s`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should try explain better your question instead of just paste your program and say that you have a problem. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Have you ever heard of function parameters or return values? Why so many globals?

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of problems with your program.

If the .dat file does not exist, then the fopen will fail, leaving the file pointer as NULL.
The subsequent fscanf will also not work, which is why you get 0 for the record count.  The behaviour of feof with a NULL file pointer is undefined, so that's probably where you are hanging.  By all rights, this program should crash.